# How to integrate this Prandtl-Meyer function

Tags: calculus, integration

[image]

[image: The figure of antiderivative]

[image]

This is the [Prandtl-Meyer function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prandtl%E2%80%93Meyer_function) that can be found in any aerodynamics textbook. However, none of those books gave detailed steps of obtaining this integration. Could you please give me any hints on how to attack this integration?

Comment: Try **integrate (x^2-1)^(1/2)/x/(1+k^2 x^2)** . WA gives something nicer than  **integrate (x^2-1)^(1/2)/x/(1+k x^2)** . Recombine the logarithms. Still hidden complex numbers but better.

Comment: An interesting problem would be to compute $M$ for a given value of $I(M)$. Do you know if this has been addressed anywhere ?

Comment: I did not find the application case of computing M from a given value of I(M). It might be due to the reason that usually the data type are in the form of "I(M2)-I(M1)".

Comment: I just asked because, from a numerical point of view, the problem is interesting. May I confess that I cannot resist an equation ? Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you consider the problem of the antiderivative, that is to say, compute
$$I(M)=\int\frac{\sqrt{M^2-1}}{M \left(1+k M^2\right)}\,dM$$  I am almost sure that Mathematica will give a result for it (may be messy, but a result). Try it and, please, report in the post the result you obtain.

Now, with regard to the integral, what I suspect is that could exist a problem for the evaluation at the lower bound. What I suggest is that you study the limit of $I(M)$ when $M \to 1$. This could explain why you do not get the result.

Trying to compute it, let
$$u=\sqrt{M^2-1} \implies M=\sqrt{u^2+1}\implies dM=\frac{u}{\sqrt{u^2+1}}\,du$$ which makes
$$I=\int \frac{u^2}{\left(u^2+1\right) \left(k u^2+(k+1)\right)}\,du$$ Now, partial fraction decomposition
$$\frac{u^2}{\left(u^2+1\right) \left(k u^2+(k+1)\right)}=\frac{k+1}{k u^2+(k+1)}-\frac{1}{u^2+1}$$ and things are becoming simple.
$$I=\frac{\sqrt{k+1}}{\sqrt{k}} \tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{\sqrt{k}
   }{\sqrt{k+1}}u\right)-\tan ^{-1}(u)$$

Back to $M$ and simplifying the radicals,
$$I(M)=\sqrt{\frac{k+1}{k}}\tan ^{-1}\left(\sqrt{\frac{k}{k+1}(M^2-1)} \right)-\tan ^{-1}\left(\sqrt{M^2-1}\right)$$ which is the final result for the definite integral since $I(1)=0$.

Make $k=\frac 12 (\gamma -1)$ to get the result given in the Wikipedia page.

Comment: Thank you so much. The answer is very clear. The antiderivative is updated. I cannot figure out where the complex part comes from or eliminate it.

Comment: @8cold8hot. You are very welcome ! As I suspected, using the antiderivative you give, $I(1)$ is **indeterminate**. Could try to compute it and see if I am correct ?

Comment: @8cold8hot. You can recombine the two logarithms making the product of their arguments; this will remove the $i$'s but you will stay with hidden complex numbers.

Comment: I updated the question to include the figure of I(1). If I use the FullSimply function in the Mathematica, it can give a determinate result.

Comment: @8cold8hot. Good to know but the problem is that this limit is again a complex number.